# Formatar célula no DataGrid em tempo de execução C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Estou criando um DataGridView automaticamente com uma coluna  de horário e estou usando o formato de tempo 00:00, como segue abaixo.

```
dgvhorario.ColumnCount = 1;
dgvhorario.Columns[0].Name = "Horário";
dgvhorario.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "t";
dgvhorario.Columns[0].Width = 80;
```

Mas na execução, não está aparecendo a máscara de horas: 00:00

Alguém sabe me dizer como corrigir isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Experimente usar isso:

```
dataGridViewCellStyle.Format = "hh:mm"; //mudei para facilitar o entendimento
this.date.DefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle;
```

Fiz um pequeno exemplo aqui:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
  public class Form1 : Form
  {
    DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();
    public Form1()
    {
      this.Controls.Add(dgv);
      DataTable dt = new DataTable();
      dt.Columns.Add("Current Time", typeof(DateTime));
      dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.Now });
      dgv.DataSource = dt;
      dgv.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "hh:mm";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Seu código não funcionou amigo jpklzm. Há como explicar melhor

Comment: Qual tipo de dado você usa para passar o valor da célula? Pega o time de um dateTime ou passa por string?

Comment: Nesse jeito que você está apresentado não consigo em tempo de execulsão, ou seja quando inicio o formulário e vou escrever algo na célula ela não formata automaticamente